# R data.table rolling join "mult" not working as expected

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have two data.frames each with a time series. My goal ist to use the timeseries of df2 to mark the closest timestamp in df1. Each timestamp in df2 should only mark ONE timestamp in df1!

```
dates1 <-  as.POSIXct(c("2015-10-26 12:00:00","2015-10-26 13:00:00","2015-10-26 14:00:00"))
values1 <- c("a","b","c")

dates2 <- as.POSIXct(c("2015-10-26 12:05:00","2015-10-26 13:55:00"))
values2 <- c("A","C")

df1 <- data.frame(dates1, values1)
df2 <- data.frame(dates2, values2)
```

desired outcome:

```
                dates2 values2 values1
1: 2015-10-26 12:00:00       A       a
2: 2015-10-26 13:00:00       NA      b
3: 2015-10-26 14:00:00       C       c
```

In order to achieve this, I'm converting the data.frames to data.tables and using the rolling joing "nearest" like so:

```
dt1 <- data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table(df2)

setkey(dt1,"dates1")
setkey(dt2,"dates2")

dt3 <- dt2[dt1,roll = "nearest"]

                dates2 values2 values1
1: 2015-10-26 12:00:00       A       a
2: 2015-10-26 13:00:00       A       b
3: 2015-10-26 14:00:00       C       c
```

The values2 "A" is used twice, once for the 12:00 timestamp and once for 13:00. I want each value2 to be used only once, and consulting the data.table manual I would expect to solve this problem with using the option *mult = "first"*.

```
dt3 <- dt2[dt1,roll = "nearest", mult = "first"]
```

This results in the same output, "A" is used twice. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When running `dt2[dt1, roll = "nearest"]` you are basically saying "*return the rows from `dt2` according to the nearest join to **each row** in `dt1` using the key*. So

- `dates2` in row **one** in `dt2` is the nearest to `dates1` in row **one** in `dt1`
- `dates2` in row **one** in `dt2` is the nearest to  `dates1` in row **two** in `dt1`
- `dates2` in row **two** in `dt2` is the nearest to  `dates1` in row **three** in `dt1`

Hence,

```
dt2[dt1, roll = "nearest"]
#                 dates2 values2 values1
# 1: 2015-10-26 12:00:00       A       a
# 2: 2015-10-26 13:00:00       A       b
# 3: 2015-10-26 14:00:00       C       c
```

Which are **all** the rows from `dt1` with the joined `values2` from `dt2`.

---

Instead, we want to join the other way around, namely "*extract `values2` from `dt2` according to the nearest join by **each row** in `dt2` using the key and update the matched rows in `dt1`*", namely

```
dt1[dt2, roll = "nearest", values2 := i.values2] 
dt1
#                 dates1 values1 values2
# 1: 2015-10-26 12:00:00       a       A
# 2: 2015-10-26 13:00:00       b      NA
# 3: 2015-10-26 14:00:00       c       C
```

---

Some additional notes

- You don't need to wrap first to `data.frame` and then to `data.table`, you can just do `dt1 <- data.table(dates1, values1)` and etc.
- While you at it, you can already set the key on the fly using `key` parameter `data.table`, namely `dt1 <- data.table(dates1, values1, key = "dates1")` and etc.
- Or you can skip setting keys all together and use `on` instead (V 1.9.6+), namely `dt1[dt2, roll = "nearest", values2 := i.values2, on = c(dates1 = "dates2")]`
- Finally, please refrain from making unnecessary copies, e.g., instead of `<-` and `data.table(df)` use `:=` and `setDT(df)`, see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for more information

Comment: @ David Arenburg: Thank you so much for your help! I keep reusing this script and your other inputs all the time. But what is this magic you did here. "values2 := i.values2". Where does this "i." come from? I scanned the documentation for this feature, but didnt find an explenation..

Comment: `i.` represent the values taken from the data set in the `i` argument. If you do `dt1[dt2]` then `dt2` is in the `i`th argument of `dt1` because as you may know a `data.table` objects is of a form of `DT[i, j, by]`. So if you want to make sure you are extracting columns from `dt2` when doing `dt1[dt2]`, then it's better to use `i.` (in case there are same columns in both data sets).